# What is ActivityRef while creating a Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

The code below is from the article 'Make your first provider/network request' in [Riverpod documentation](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/first_request).

```
//activity.dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';
import 'activity.dart';

// Necessary for code-generation to work
part 'provider.g.dart';

/// This will create a provider named `activityProvider`
/// which will cache the result of this function.
@riverpod
Future<Activity> activity(ActivityRef ref) async {
  // Using package:http, we fetch a random activity from the Bored API.
  final response = await http.get(Uri.https('boredapi.com', '/api/activity'));
  // Using dart:convert, we then decode the JSON payload into a Map data structure.
  final json = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  // Finally, we convert the Map into an Activity instance.
  return Activity.fromJson(json);
}
```

In the above code, I could not figure out what is ActivityRef and where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

`ActivityRef` is an automatically generated reference used by Riverpod for managing the state of providers. It's generated by the code generation provided by the riverpod_annotation package.

The ActivityRef is not explicitly defined in the code snippet because it's generated behind the scenes when you use Riverpod's code generation mechanism. When you annotate a function with `@riverpod`, its reference (like `ActivityRef`) is generated automatically when you run the code generation step (using `flutter pub run build_runner build`).

Answer (score 0):

`ActivityRef` is a [`Ref`](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/Ref-class.html) that is generated by [riverpod_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_generator) when you use a code-gen functional provider. The name itself is taken from the name of the function you defined, so because the function in that code is named `activity`, the generated `Ref` will be `ActivityRef`. If for example you define another provider like this:

```dart
@riverpod
Future<Activity> banana(BananaRef ref) async {
  // ...
}
```

As you can see, the name of the `ref` type should follow the function name, otherwise the code generation will fail.

This `ActivityRef` is defined in the generated file as a mixin or typedef, so for example if the provider definition is in a file named `activity.dart`, `ActivityRef` will be generated in a file called `activity.g.dart`.

---

You can see an example of this pattern shown in the example project [`pub`](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/tree/master/examples/pub) from the riverpod repository on GitHub. A function called `likedPackages` is defined in [`lib/detail.dart` (line 36)](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/pub/lib/detail.dart#L36), and the generated typedef `LikedPackagesRef` is defined in [`lib/detail.g.dart` (line 177)](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blob/master/examples/pub/lib/detail.g.dart#L177).